# How to apply different validation rule according to polymorphic association type (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, polymorphic-associations

I have Rails polymorphic model and I want to apply different validations according to *associated class*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class name is in the `_type` column for instance in the following setup:

```
class Comment
   belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Post
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

the comment class is going to have the `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` fields.  `commentable_type` is the class name and `commentable_id` is the foreign key.  If you wanted to to a validation through comment for post-specific comments, you could do something like this:

```
validate :post_comments_are_long_enough

def post_comments_are_long_enough
  if self.commentable_type == "Post"  && self.body.size < 10
    @errors.add_to_base "Comment should be 10 characters"
  end
end
```

OR, and I think I like this better:

```
validates_length_of :body, :mimimum => 10, :if => :is_post?

def is_post?
  self.commentable_type == "Post"
end
```

if you have several validations, I would recommend this syntax instead:

```
with_options :if => :is_post? do |o|
  o.validates_length_of :body, :minimum => 10
  o.validates_length_of :body, :maximum => 100
end
```

Comment: That's the shitty part. Can't access attributes from inside polymorphic model.

"undefined method `itemable_type' for #<Class:0xb5fd87b0>"

Comment: Life would be perfect otherwise... :(

Comment: if you are writing the above code directly into your class that would fail, it would only be available for an instance, not the class.  Add the `define_method` code into a instance method and it should pass.

Answer (score 1):

The [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) method is what you need.
You just have to link this method to the polymorphic model and it will check if the associated models are valid.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  validates_associated :commentable
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: commentable

  validates_length_of :body, :minimum => 10
  validates_length_of :body, :maximum => 100
end
```

Comment: @KickButtowski Maybe because you don't have the attribute `body` on your model ?