# Rails conditional validation based on polymorphic type

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, inheritance, devise, polymorphism

I am working with a Rails polymorphic inheritance configuration - I have the following setup:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :rolable, :polymorphic => true

Student < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :user, :as => :rolable
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :user, :as => :rolable
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

I want to be able to capture email address for teachers and a username for students (who won't typically have an email address). I defined those as attributes of the User model, but now I'm stuck when I try to do validations for Student and Teacher. I didn't define them in their respective models because I'm using Devise and there will be other user types. Abstracting what is currently type to a Role pattern isn't a good fit for my particular scenario either.

Since username and email are properties of User what I basically want to do is check if the rolable_type field from the polymorphic relationship is type student and if so, make username required and email not, but in the new method that property isn't set. However Rails 'knows' this is a Student, so it feels like there's some way to check the instance type. The closest link I've found to what I'm shooting for is the third comment to the accepted answer in this question: [How to apply different validation rule according to polymorphic association type (Rails)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218993/how-to-apply-different-validation-rule-according-to-polymorphic-association-type), but I'm having trouble getting the method_missing syntax correct as I'm not experienced with metaprogramming. Am I on the right track with this? Or is there a simpler way? Or should I move the properties to the polymorphic models instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply different validation rule according to polymorphic association type (Rails)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218993/how-to-apply-different-validation-rule-according-to-polymorphic-association-type)